# 48h Countdown with reset after 24h

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a countdown. It should count down 48 hours until 12am of the next day depending on the actual time. But the countdown should reset on 12am of the actual day and start again to count down 48h until 12am of the next day.

At the moment it just counts down 24 hours depending on the actual time until 24:00.

How can this be done?

Here is what I have:

```js
var date;
var display = document.getElementById('time');
setInterval(function(){
    date = new Date();
    var currenthours = date.getHours();
    var hours;
    var minutes;
    var secondes;
    if (currenthours != 23){
        if (currenthours < 23)
            hours = 23 - currenthours;
        else hours = 23 + (23 - currenthours);
        minutes = 60 - date.getMinutes();
        secondes = 60 - date.getSeconds();
    display.innerHTML = hours + 'h ' + minutes + 'm ' +secondes + 's';
    }
    else display.innerHTML = 'LIVE NOW';
},1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='time'></span>
```

Comment: "*But the countdown should reset on 12am of the actual day and start again to count down 48h until 12am of the next day*". A day is 24 hours. How would you expect a timer to reset after 24 hours but count 48 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add 24 hours to your result to get the 48 hours interval.

```js
var date;
    var display = document.getElementById('time');
    setInterval(function(){
        date = new Date();
        var currenthours = date.getHours();
        var hours;
        var minutes;
        var secondes;
        if (currenthours != 23){
            if (currenthours < 23)
                hours = 47 - currenthours;
            else hours = 47 + (23 - currenthours);
            minutes = 60 - date.getMinutes();
            secondes = 60 - date.getSeconds();
        display.innerHTML = hours + 'h ' + minutes + 'm ' +secondes + 's';
        }
        else display.innerHTML = 'LIVE NOW';
    },1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="time"></div>
```